# Display private roads to mapbox without displaying to other users and use navigation sdk to navigate

Tags: google-maps, mapbox, mapbox-android

I wanted to display private roads to Mapbox without uploading to public maps. And wanted to use navigation SDK to navigate over private roads.
How can i create private roads and add as layer to mapbox, so that navigation sdk can identify as road and show navigation over that roads.
Please help

Comment: Your wishes contradict each other. You don't want to share your private roads, but how navigation should work if you don't share your private roads?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish? If you want to allow destination routing to somewhere that is on a private roadway, adding that roadway to OpenStreetMap with the appropriate access: tags should cause routers to avoid using it unless routing to a destination on it (i.e. it will not suddenly become a preferred shortcut for automated routing engines).

If even admitting the way exists in public is problematic, you'd probably have to maintain your own database of ways, add the ways in there, and not share it publicly. I don't know what implications the OSM licensing would have that might inhibit doing this.